# Embedded Flash displays white screen

Tags: flash, swfobject

I am using SWFObject to embed a flash game into a website I am working on. For some reason, all that appears is a white screen (nothing loads), but, if I go to the SWF directly it plays... I have tried everything I can think of to get this flash to play...

```
Flash Version: 11.5.31.137
```

Comment: Can you show your code or URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the debug version of flash player and see what the output is. I suspect it will give you a clue about what is wrong.